# Does Compiling My Android App On A Different Computer Create A New Signing Certificate?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I created an app on my Windows PC and from that PC I published the app to the Google Play Store. I have migrated(transferred via external hard drive) all my projects from my PC to my Mac.

I am now wondering will compiling that same app on the Mac cause it to create a new certificate?

The reason I would like to know is because I want to publish an update and would prefer to work on the project on the Mac but I don't want a problem to occur, that when I decide to publish the app from the Mac the Play Store will see a different certificate and the app will be published as if it were a totally brand new APK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, it is not computer-dependent.

Make sure you copy the **Keystore** you've been using to sign it from your old computer to the new one and everything will be exactly the same.

The **Keystore** is (just) the file in which all your keys are saved (and usually has a .jks extension).

The [main documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) states:

> A keystore is a binary file that contains a set of private keys. You
>   must keep your keystore in a safe and secure place.
>
> A private key represents the entity to be identified with the app,
>   such as a person or a company.

So as long as you are identified with the same **private key** (located in your **keystore**), you will be fine.

Comment: Also for everyone who view this answer it is worth to note that, if using Android Studio, the new location(directory path) of the KeyStore should be placed in the gradle. EG: storeFile file('/Users/johndoe/Documents/TheKeySoreFolder/app-release.jks')

Answer (score 3):

Every installation of Android Studio has it's own debug signing key which is used to install apps on your device. However, when you sign an app for distribution on Google Play, you're supposed to use a separate keystore that you've generated and password protected. The overview of this process is here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

The good news is, you can then move that release keystore to any computer you want and use it to sign release builds for the Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the signing certificate you used on the first machine to the second machine, there will be no problem.  The build and sign process should be platform agnostic (unless your build code makes assumptions about the host platform).

Answer (score 1):

By default it will use a different debug certificate on every machine.  You should explicitly create and use a non-debug key for publication.  You may not want to check the signing key into source control, so you'll have to copy it to other computers manually.